# How do I find out why my 404 handler is generating a 500 error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here is my 404 view:

```
def handler_404(request):                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    response = render(request, '404.html')
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

It seems this code is generating a 500 error, but I'm not seeing any kind of error output in the terminal where I have the django development server running.

I had to set `DEBUG = False` to see if my custom 404 page would be rendered, seems it isn't working but generating a 500 error.

Update #1:

I have tried adding a URL to my list of URLs, e.g. `path('404/', my_views.my_404_view)` and then visited `/404` in the browser, and the template loads and no error appears.

Update #2:

I've also tried adding the following code to enable detailed log output in the terminal while `DEBUG` is set to `False`.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          'file': {
           'level': 'DEBUG',
           'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
           'filename': 'log.django',
       },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

All I see in the terminal is this:

```
Internal Server Error: /asdf
"GET /asdf HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

Comment: What happens when `DEBUG` is `True`? `500` or `404`?

Comment: 404, but it doesn't display my 404.html template, just the standard Django debugging 404

Comment: which version of Django?

Answer (score 0):

It seems my function wasn't accepting the required parameters:

I changed this:

```
def handler_404(request):
```

To this:

```
def handler_404(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
```